# Скролл слайдера по свайпу

Tags: javascript, slider

Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот слайдер на мобильных листался свайпом, а не кликом по следующему слайду. Как такое можно реализовать? http://koorub.site/mb/

Answer (score 0):

Возможные варианты:

1. Написать кучу кода для распознавания движения свайпа.
2. Использовать готовые библиотеки типа [этой](https://swiperjs.com/). Пользуюсь давно, куча документации и примеров, свайп есть, клик есть и т.д. Рекомендую

Comment: почему кучу кода?

Comment: SwiperJS у меня не  листается свайпом. MacOS 12.0.1 (21A559) Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93 (arm64). Потому SwiperJS уг.

Comment: Какой код использовался?

Comment: Который на главной странице switerjs.com

Comment: При этом свайпы работают на [карусели на чистом CSS](https://codepen.io/maoberlehner/pen/abvJPVy). Потому CSS рулит а scrolljacking - это зло.